# mongodb sorting by two fields in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

Im using mongodb and mongoose for developing an application. i have a collection named product that has following fields:

```
{
 color:String,
 sizes: [{type: String}],
 gender: String, //can be women / men / kids
 price: {
    type: Number, required: true, min: 0
  },
 likes: {type: Number, default: 0},
 views: {type: Number, default: 0},
}
```

and i want to use aggregate to filter documents by size L and also perform descending sort on likes and ascending sort on prices.
here is the query i'm using :

```
aggregate([{$match:{sizes:['L']}},{$sort:{price:1,likes:-1}}])
```

but i get the result sorting the documents only by first field in $sort object, that is the price and they're not sorted by likes.
so what's the problem? i tried different fields and orders and every time got the same result.

Comment: Can you post sample to data to support your claim. The default behaviour of `sort()` is to sort by the first field you've provided and use the second field to sort when the first field of 2 documents to match is equal i.e. the documents would only be sorted by `likes` if their `price` is the same.

Comment: so how can i sort the documents by two fields?or more than two fields.is there any plugins or methods?

Answer (score -1):

According to MongoDB docs at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

> [image]

$sort method you use has correct format, are you sure you have any likes in records you want to sort? Also check if your MongoDB is in version which supports format you are using. Below example is almost same as yours, just simplified sizes query, you do not need to make ["L"] when sizes array contains just strings.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "sizes": "L"
        }
    },
    { 
        "$sort": {
            "price": 1,
            "likes": -1
        }
    }
])
```